# Querying two tables with one query

Tags: mysql

I want to get two separate tables by executing one query in MySQL. If you know how, please reply.

Comment: Before this gets closed, I suggest you fill out some more information. In particular, what have you already tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "get two separate tables"?  It is certainly possible to query two tables with one statement.  Read up about joins.

Comment: Not enough information in question - the answer might be some type of join, might be a union, which might imply row type casting. Can you provide a concrete example of the inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Or even a stored proc with 2 resultsets, anything is possible, depends highly on environment, why the need for a single query arises, and how the data relates.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply perform a join on the database.

```
table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor ON conditional_expr
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Why the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that because there isn't really a way to retrieve two different datasets from one query. Nor do I know why you would want to do this.

Comment: actually I try to created dynamic rows in PDF by using Jasper report.
In pdf i print two table for that i want to print two table by single query

Comment: UNION the tables together? We really don't have enough information

Answer (score -1):

No enough information,if you want to produce two datasets its possible using a stored procedure which will split the data from your table and insert into two temporary tables,thats my take on it,but if you supply some more information maybe we can get a clear scope of your problem